# Execute map on buffered flux in parallel

Tags: java, spring-webflux, project-reactor

I have a flux where all values come in at the same time. I want to execute a time intensive task on chunks of these values in parallel. Why does this code execute each mapping on the same thread and not parallel?

```java
@Test
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    Flux.just("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")
        .buffer(2)
        .publishOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .map(this::doTimeintensiveStuff)
        .doOnNext(val -> {
            log.info("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "]  " + val);
        })
        .blockLast();
}

private String doTimeintensiveStuff(List<String> input) {
    return String.join(", ", input); // this is just a place holder
}
```

My log output looks like this

```
Aug. 07, 2023 4:44:50 PM de.test.ParallelTest lambda$1
INFORMATION: [parallel-1]  a, b
Aug. 07, 2023 4:44:50 PM de.test.ParallelTest lambda$1
INFORMATION: [parallel-1]  c, d
Aug. 07, 2023 4:44:50 PM de.test.ParallelTest lambda$1
INFORMATION: [parallel-1]  e, f
Aug. 07, 2023 4:44:50 PM de.stest.ParallelTest lambda$1
INFORMATION: [parallel-1]  g
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It supposed to be:

```
public void test() throws InterruptedException {
    Flux.just("a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g")
        .buffer(2)
        .parallel()
        .runOn(Schedulers.parallel())
        .map(this::doTimeintensiveStuff)
        .sequential()
        .doOnNext(val -> {
            log.info("[" + Thread.currentThread().getName() + "]  " + val);
        })
        .blockLast();
}
```

Because `.publishOn(..)` doesn't spin off new threads, it just defines the current thread. But `.parallel().runOn(..)` uses parallel threads for execution.